# is there any formula to break a line from a specific text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there any formula to break a line from a specific text?
e.g.

> Q.1 This is Question number one? Ans. True

> Q.2 This is Question number Two? Ans. false

i have above text where first part is Question and the second part is Answer. This text is in a cell and i want a formula to break the line from "Ans." text to next line without overwriting the text in the next line.

**output should look like this**:

Q.1 This is Question number one?

Ans. True

Q.2 This is Question number Two?

Ans. false

Comment: What do you mean by "new line"? Within the same cell - or shall the answer be in a new cell?

Answer (score 3):

What about:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A2,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,{"";"Ans."}&TEXTSPLIT(b,,"Ans.")))),1)
```

Just so we avoid `TEXTJOIN()` and thus it's limits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula to have the answer in a new line in the same cell - if e.g. the text is in A1

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1," Ans.", CHAR(10) & "Ans.")`

Don't forget to set textwrap for the cell :-) otherwise you won't see the result.

Comment: "Ans." should be in the next row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this, if you are using **MS365**,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",,SUBSTITUTE(A1:A2,"?","? |")&" |"),"@"," |",1))
```

---

**Edit :**

Another alternative way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=LET(_string,SUBSTITUTE(A1:A2,"Ans.","| Ans."),
TOCOL(HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(_string," | "),TEXTAFTER(_string," | "))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect, but if your list of question and answers in located in column A, and they ALWAYS have "Ans." (case-sensitive), then if you auto-fill the following formula (double the current row count) into an empty column it should give you question and answer on the next row.

`=IF(ROW()/2=ROUND(ROW()/2,0),TRIM(MID(INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)),FIND("Ans.",INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)),1),1+LEN(INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)))-FIND("Ans.",INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)),1))),TRIM(MID(INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)),1,FIND("Ans.",INDIRECT("A"&ROUND(ROW()/2,0)),1)-1)))`